# Num Lock Key indicator for Win8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

My computer doesn't have a Num Lock key or Caps Lock Key visual indicator, which sucks, since it's frequently annoying to press numbers on the numpad key only for your computer to do weird stuff.

Is there software out there that will allow me to see the status of whether or not NumLock or CapsLock is on? Preferably, can it also work on the Start Menu (before you log in)

Comment: PC setting-> Ease of Access->Keyboard -> Turn on Toggle keys. Then pressing caps lock or num-lock key can produce a distinctive beep.

Comment: @I.. While I appreciate the input, sometimes I use my computer in public settings, like the library or other areas, and would rather not have a computer going "beep beep" constantly

Answer (score 3):

Binary Fortress **[TrayStatus](http://www.binaryfortress.com/TrayStatus/)**:

- freeware
- Num Lock, Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, Alt key, Ctrl key, Shift key, Windows key, Hard Drive activity (read or write) with current speed in a tooltip
- separate tray icons
- doesn't work before you log in
- depends on .NET framework (no problem on Windows 8)

[image]

Comment: I took a look at this, and though I was interested, the lack of support for the log-in screen annoys me

Answer (score 2):

**[Keyboard LEDs](http://keyboard-leds.com/)**:

- freeware
- on-screen display and tray icons (customizable)
- lightweight
- it doesn't work before you log in
- audio indicator of changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used TrayStatus. When I got a new tablet I tried another program when I tried to remember the name. It is real basic bit is doing the job for me [[1]](http://roidayan.com/keyboard-indicator/).

Comment: What is the purpose of that **[1]**-link at the end of your answer, how does it related to the actual content of your answer?

Comment: https://github.com/roidayan/KeyboardIndicator only shows something when the related keyboard key(s) is pressed, which is not the point of the question. Todd, could you please provide a link to TrayStatus and describe exactly what it does? Thanks!